# How to display multi Jenkins jobs execution status in all node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My project have several jobs running in Jenkins, and each job is configured to run in 4~8 nodes(we have 8 nodes in total), we want to have a web page view to monitor the status like the following:

[image]

Is there any plugin could help show this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the version of your Jenkins instance, exact configuration and needs, you may want to take a look at following plugins:

1. [Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin). My favorite one. It allows you to easily build a dashboard with selected builds and display their status in clear and even animated way.
2. [Radiator View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin). This one is not as nice in design but it appears it provides a bit more settings.
3. [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View). It is more old-school in design, like 1.50* versions of Jenkins, but it can display way more than just a job status. See plugin page for details, I'll just mention configurable axises and availability of custom extensions.
4. [Jenkins Job Dashing Widget](https://kj187.github.io/dashing-jenkins_job/). Last, but not least in my review. I never used this one, and it appears to have some Node.js dependencies but it creates an easily understandable dashboard and it looks like it can be customized more or less easily.

These are some of the options you have here. I'm not sure any of listed plugins will allow you to draw a grid 100% like you state in question but some of them may eventually suite your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the plugin you are looking for is the [Label Linked Jobs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Label+Linked+Jobs+Plugin)

This plugin allows you to define the labels (i.e.: nodes) which you want linked together grouped by job. You should then be able to achieve the dashboard view you have described.